# Identify the number of a Word table (Selected or by Title)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I'm trying to program a macro in excel to export data to a word report. This data will go into several Word tables. All data transfer commands are now ready and working. However, in order to make this transfers more dynamic, I am inserting Titles and creating bookmarks for all tables into word report.

The problem is:
Via excel macro, I am able to select the Word tables through the following code:

```
oDoc.Bookmarks("Table_name").Range.Select
```

However, I cannot transfer the data to a specific cell of this table.

I know the by Word there is this command, but I can't use with Excel.

`ActiveDocument.Range(0,Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Tables.Count)`

Would anyone know how to help me?

Before that I was transferring the data referencing the table number but the problem is that whenever we revise the report to include new tables my reference ends up getting lost and I have to do table count again to transfer the data in the right table .

Well, that's it! Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

Comment: `oDoc.Tables.Count` ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back.  I believe this command will not work.  this command you sent only works for the total count of the number of tables there are in the document.  What I need is a command that returns me the number of that table that is selected.  Remembering that I need to do this through Excel.  Another alternative would be for me to add row and column of this selected table to transfer the information from Excel to Word.

Comment: You can loop thru the table collection and look for the table you want that way. There is no easy convenient way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Could you please show me how then I can transfer data **from Excel to a Word table** without getting stuck on the table number? I'm trying to get rid of this problem of fixing the table number, so if in the future I add or remove tables from this report I don't have to keep renumbering it every time. I have reports with more than 100 tables, so imagine the work it is every time to recount.

I appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: MS Word does not give each one a name, so you have to come up with your own system. When you create the document with all the tables, you can give each one a name... using the `Table.Descr` property. `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Descr = "myTable"` then when you look for them, loop thru them and find that `Descr` - Or you can set up some constants for the `Index` if that helps. Or you can create one routine that sets up some variables by scanning the document that you run just once.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!!

From the test I performed here, I believe that this command you gave me will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on how your document is constructed. If the bookmarks enclose content, then you can use:

```
oDoc.Bookmarks("Table_name").Range.Tables(1)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back.  I'll test this command and then get back to you with the information if it worked or not.

Comment: If the above command doesn't work, do you know any other way for me to be able to call Word tables by the Title inserted in properties and transfer information from Excel to cells of these tables?

Comment: @Lrossan - The title property isn’t an index into the tables collection. To find a table by title you’ll need to loop through the tables collection until you find the one you’re looking for.

Comment: Could you please show me how then I can transfer data **from Excel to a Word table** without getting stuck on the table number? I'm trying to get rid of this problem of fixing the table number, so if in the future I add or remove tables from this report I don't have to keep renumbering it every time. I have reports with more than 100 tables, so imagine the work it is every time to recount.

I appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

MS Word does not give each one a name, so you have to come up with your own system.

When you create the document with all the tables, you can give each one a name... using the `Table.Descr` property.

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Descr = "myTable"
```

Then when you look for them, loop thru them and find that `Descr`

```
For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
  If t.Descr = "myTable" Then

    ' do something

  End If
Next
```

Or you can set up some constants for the Index if that helps.

Or you can create one routine that sets up variables by scanning the document that you would need to run only once.